# Angular Pipe: Cannot replace /n

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have been trying to make a pipe to replace certain characters in a message, this is the code for the pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'replace'})
export class ReplacePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    console.log(value);
    let newValue = value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
    console.log(newValue);
    return `${newValue}`;
  }
}
```

I am using it on the page like this:

```
  <ion-card-content [innerHtml]="message | linky | replace"></ion-card-content>
```

The Issue: It works when the replace statement is something is like this:

```
let newValue = value.replace('bit', '<br>');
```

But is doesn't do anything when it looks like this:(I need to get it working for this)

```
let newValue = value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
```

I can't seem to figure out where am I going wrong.

Comment: No I have not what would I be checking against?

Comment: You sure that 'linky' not messing up in the middle?

Comment: No, I got it to work. I posted the answer below

Comment: erm.. this is wired that people ask on SO, Don't accept any answer and post their own. do they get point?

Comment: Fun Fact: You can't accept your own answers for at least 2 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it work by putting `<br>` is `double quotes` and adding an extra `\` to`\n`. I don't know why I needed to do that to make it work but it works perfectly now. Here is the solution:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'replace'})
export class ReplacePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    console.log(value);
    if(value) {
    let newValue = value.replace(/\\n/g, "<br>").replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
    console.log(newValue);
    return `${newValue}`;
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say it doesn't work does that mean that the console.log(newValue) outputs as "something \n something" and not "something 
 something"? Is there an error message of any sort?

I just took your exact code and tested it [here](http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html) and it worked.

```
var value = "asd \n more stuff";
console.log(value)
let newValue = value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
console.log(newValue)
```

Comment: Console.log print ""something \n something" There is no error message. But I figured it out posting the solution in few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `\n` character is in your string? It is probably there as a string. Give this a try: `let newValue = value.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>');` The reason why you need is is because your string actuaally cointains `"\n"` and not the `newline` character. In a regex `\n` is a newline character and `\\n` is `"\n"` as string.

Comment: It is there, I just got it to work and Posted the solution ! Thank you !

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, that helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was handling return to line that way too but just figured out that you can easily display these line's jump with css. `{ white-space: pre; }`